# How can I compute the number of the torsion in a graph and conformation? Is there an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a graph with 4 nodes, how can I compute all the possible numbers of the torsion possible around the node and all the possible numbers of conformation? In the example, I would aspect to have 2 main nodes (the black one) that act as a point in which the other two are free to rotate

[image]

Comment: Can you define what torsion and conformation mean? I'm not familiar with those terms.

Comment: It is very unlikely that your question fits both "graph" and "graph-theory" tags. Edit your question to pick a single one of them (`graph-theory` ?).

Comment: @templatetypedef immagine to have a molecule with atoms, and atoms rotate and reach a more stable conformation. like happen in protein folding

Comment: How do you measure "more stable?" Is there some way of quantifying that? Also, what's the difference between torsion and conformation?

Comment: @templatetypedef In the case of protein folding the more stable is the one with the lowest energy.

Comment: @Python How do you define "lowest energy?" Is there some energy function you have defined?